# OMNET++: How to move node in a discrete NxN space in INET 4.0?

Tags: omnet++, inet

As the question implies, I would like to move my `AdhocHost` in a discrete `(100m x 100m)` space. That is, for example assume that the node is in `(0,0)m`, then it waits for one second, and then it "teleports" to `(0,1)m`, without crossing the distance between the two positions.
How may I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a mobility model. Store the actual integer coordinates as the state. Create a timer event that fires on each second, and on that event modify the coordinates according to your rules. You can start from scratch or you may take a look at the stationary mobility module as an example.

About the mobility models in INET: https://inet.omnetpp.org/users-guide/chap22.html

Answer (score 0):

So here's how I did it using a little trick.
My Mobility Model is based on `TractorMobility`.
After extending from the class `TractorMobility`, I added another `Coord` variable called `vLastPosition` (which stands for Virtual Last Position). What this variable does is identical to that of the `lastPosition` variable of `TractorMobility` and stores the last position of my host. And then when it comes to moving the host and thus setting the `lastPosition` variable, I set it based on the integer part of the `vLastPosition` coordinate.
 Therefore my Mobility Module still "thinks" that the host is moving constantly, while the host moves ONLY when the integer part of its position changes.
The `.ned` file of my Module is:

```
import inet.mobility.single.TractorMobility;
import inet.mobility.contract.IMobility;

simple OfflinePhaseMobility extends TractorMobility like IMobility
{
    parameters:
        double hopSize @unit(m) = default(1m);
        @class(inet::OfflinePhaseMobility);
}
```

Here's the header file of my custom mobility class (`OfflinePhaseMobility.h`):

```
#ifndef OFFLINEPHASEMOBILITY_H_
#define OFFLINEPHASEMOBILITY_H_

#include "inet/common/INETDefs.h"
#include "inet/mobility/single/TractorMobility.h"

namespace inet{
class OfflinePhaseMobility : public TractorMobility{
protected:
    virtual void setTargetPosition() override;
    virtual void move() override;
    Coord vLastPosition;
};
}//ns inet

#endif /* OFFLINEPHASEMOBILITY_H_ */
```

And this is my `OfflinePhaseMobility.cc` file:

```
#include "OfflinePhaseMobility.h"
namespace inet{

Define_Module(OfflinePhaseMobility);

void OfflinePhaseMobility::setTargetPosition()
{
    int sign;
    Coord positionDelta = Coord::ZERO;
    switch (step % 4) {
        case 0:
            positionDelta.x = x2 - x1;
            break;

        case 1:
        case 3:
            sign = (step / (2 * rowCount)) % 2 ? -1 : 1;
            positionDelta.y = (y2 - y1) / rowCount * sign;
            break;

        case 2:
            positionDelta.x = x1 - x2;
            break;
    }
    step++;
    targetPosition = vLastPosition + positionDelta;
    nextChange = simTime() + positionDelta.length() / speed;
}

void OfflinePhaseMobility::move(){
        simtime_t now = simTime();
        if (now == nextChange) {
            vLastPosition = targetPosition;
            EV_INFO << "reached current target position = " << vLastPosition << endl;
            setTargetPosition();
            EV_INFO << "new target position = " << targetPosition << ", next change = " << nextChange << endl;
            lastVelocity = (targetPosition - vLastPosition) / (nextChange - simTime()).dbl();
        }
        else if (now > lastUpdate) {
            ASSERT(nextChange == -1 || now < nextChange);
            vLastPosition += lastVelocity * (now - lastUpdate).dbl();
        }
        double hopSize = par("hopSize");
int numHopsX = vLastPosition.x / hopSize;
int numHopsY = vLastPosition.y / hopSize;
double candidateX = (numHopsX * hopSize);
double deltaX = vLastPosition.x - candidateX;
if(deltaX <= hopSize/2)
    lastPosition.x = candidateX;
else
    lastPosition.x = candidateX + hopSize;
lastPosition.y = (numHopsY * hopSize);
}


}//ns inet
```

And the mobility configuration in `omnetpp.ini`:

```
*.hostA.mobility.typename = "OfflinePhaseMobility"
*.hostA.mobility.rowCount = 101
*.hostA.mobility.x1 = 0m
*.hostA.mobility.y1 = 0m
*.hostA.mobility.x2 = 100m
*.hostA.mobility.y2 = 100m
*.hostA.mobility.speed = 1mps
*.hostA.mobility.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
*.hostA.mobility.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
*.hostA.mobility.constraintAreaMaxX = 100m
*.hostA.mobility.constraintAreaMaxY = 100m
```

As you can see, I set the speed to 1mps. You may have also realized that `hopeSize` parameter is the distance between my predifined positions.
Simple as that! Hope this helps whoever that has the same problem and doesn't wish to write a mobility module from scratch.